# Inner Join in Linq Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a query

```cs
var casino = await _context.Casinos
    .Include(c => c.CasinoTableGames).ThenInclude(y => y.TableGame)
    .Include(c => c.CasinoTableGames).ThenInclude(y => y.Manufacturer)
    .Where(y => y.CasinoID == id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.CasinoID == id);
```

There is a column "Active" in CasinoTableGames table. How can I include only rows where Active is true in CasinoTableGames table.

Comment: Use a [filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since EF Core 5 you can use [filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include). Something along these lines:

```cs
var casino = await _context.Casinos
    .Include(c => c.CasinoTableGames.Where(ctg => ctg.Active))
        .ThenInclude(y => y.TableGame)
    .Include(c => c.CasinoTableGames).ThenInclude(y => y.Manufacturer)
    .Where(y => y.CasinoID == id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.CasinoID == id);
```

Note that this can be affected by previous [tracked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) operations:

> In case of tracking queries, results of Filtered Include may be unexpected due to navigation fixup. All relevant entities that have been queried for previously and have been stored in the Change Tracker will be present in the results of Filtered Include query, even if they don't meet the requirements of the filter. Consider using `NoTracking` queries or re-create the DbContext when using Filtered Include in those situations.